# How to get a callback if a file is created in a specific directory on linux

Tags: c++, linux

I wanted to know if there was a way for me to get a callback anytime a file was created in a specific directory in my c++ application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the inotify API

http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/inotify.7.html